# Oracle trigger is very slow

Tags: oracle, triggers, spatial

I have an Oracle trigger that is very slow. I would love some suggestions to improve its performance.

I have a before insert trigger from a spatial query that does a lookup and populates a column with a value. The table, called GRID_WTMA3 is 42,000 rows. When a point on the map (ESRI) is saved it looks up the spatial location (st_geometry). Based on that location I lookup the ID value in GRID_WTMA3 and populate the WU column in my TRAPPING_MERGE table. Entire trigger is below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRAPPING_MERGE_BI BEFORE INSERT
    ON TRAPPING_MERGE
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN


 if :new.ZONE is null or :new.Zone = '' then
    SELECT Z.ZONE INTO :new.ZONE FROM ZONE_MERGE_EVW Z WHERE sde.st_within (st_centroid(:new.shape), Z.shape) = 1;
  end if;  

 if :new.COUNTY is null or :new.COUNTY = '' then
    SELECT TC.CNTY_FIPS INTO :new.COUNTY FROM TEXAS_COUNTIES_4326 TC WHERE sde.st_within (st_centroid(:new.shape), TC.shape) = 1;
  end if; 


if (:new.WU is null or :new.WU = '') and :new.ZONE = 'WTMA1' then 
   SELECT G.ID into :new.WU 
     FROM GRID_WTMA1 G 
    where (sde.st_intersects (st_centroid(:new.shape), G.shape) = 1) and (sde.st_within (st_centroid(:new.shape), G.shape) = 1);  
end if;

if (:new.WU is null or :new.WU = '') and :new.ZONE = 'WTMA2' then
   SELECT G.ID into :new.WU 
     FROM GRID_WTMA2 G 
    where (sde.st_intersects (st_centroid(:new.shape), G.shape) = 1) and (sde.st_within (st_centroid(:new.shape), G.shape) = 1);  
end if;

if (:new.WU is null or :new.WU = '') and :new.ZONE = 'WTMA3' then 
   SELECT G.ID into :new.WU 
     FROM GRID_WTMA3 G 
    where (sde.st_intersects (st_centroid(:new.shape), G.shape) = 1) and (sde.st_within (st_centroid(:new.shape), G.shape) = 1); 
end if;

if (:new.WU is null or :new.WU = '') and :new.ZONE = 'WTMA4' then 
    SELECT G.ID into :new.WU 
      FROM GRID_WTMA4 G 
     where (sde.st_intersects (st_centroid(:new.shape), G.shape) = 1) and (sde.st_within (st_centroid(:new.shape), G.shape) = 1);
end if;


end;
/
```

Comment: Can't help you, but note that conditions like `:new.Zone = ''` will always return `false` because in Oracle `''` is identical to `null`, and `=` doesn't work with `null`.  So just say `if :new.ZONE is null then`

Comment: Are you inserting one row at a time and finding that slow, or are you inserting multiple rows at a time?

Comment: There is no obvious link between your trapping merge table and your grid_wtmaN tables, apart from what is happening in the st_intersects and/or st_within functions - will they always return a single row?

Comment: Only returns one row and only inserting one row at a time. No multiples.